# Scikit-learn joblib/zlib error

Tags: python, scikit-learn, zlib

I ran into the following error when trying to load a .pkl file using joblib.

```
    self.name = joblib.load(
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '../relative/directory/%s.pkl' % name)
    )
```

The above code yields the following error.

```
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 68, in read_zfile
    data = zlib.decompress(file_handle.read(), 15, length)
zlib.error: Error -3 while decompressing data: invalid distance too far back
```

Has anyone run into this issue before?

Comment: I never observed this issue myself. Can you reproduce it in a minimalistic script that does not rely on your data?

Comment: By any chance did you change the version of Python (e.g. from Python 2.7 to Python 3.3) between the call to `joblib.dump` and `joblib.save`?

Comment: No, I was unable to reproduce it, and no the version of python was not changed between joblib.dump and joblib.save.  It turns out a single file had been corrupted -- simply deleting the file and regenerating it solved my issue.  Thanks for the suggestions though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that the compressed data was corrupted somewhere along the way.